# iOS App URL is not being detected

Tags: objective-c, ios, url

I have created a custom App URL for my iOS app. The URL format is similar to this:

```
myappname://texttobeparsed
```

This works fine when I paste the URL in safari, My App opens and correctly handles the URL. The problem is that other apps such as iMessage or Notes do not recognize this as a URL.

**Why isn't this URL scheme being recognized as a URL**? Could it have to do with how I set it up in my **info.plist** file or something else?

Or, does the URL need to be in a different format to be recognized?

I know it's possible to have the system recognize it as a URL in apps other than web-browsers because I've seen it before with other apps (ex. iTunes: `itms://itunes.com/apps/appname` or Twitter: `twitter://` or Facebook: `fb://`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>There's nothing you can do about this. If the link isn't explicit (e.g. in an HTML email), these apps can just recognize a built-in set of standard URL schemes. `itms://` is one of Apple's own schemes (for the iTunes Store), so it makes sense that it is supported in addition to the standard `mailto://`, `http://`, `tel://`... schemes.</s>

**Edit:** I would guess that the information that is used to determine what constitutes a valid URL in text views etc. is cached somehow. Contrary to what I initially guessed, it seems that app-specific URLs *do* work in Notes, etc. I've tested this with `tweetbot://` for example (which I have installed) and `twitter://` (which I don't have installed) to verify that it doesn't just check for a pattern like `*://`, but actually uses information about the installed apps.

I'd suggest that you try to restart your device. If it's an issue with some cache, that might help and I don't think there's much else you could do if your URL scheme already works in Safari.

**Update:** I've installed the official Twitter app to test this, the `twitter://` scheme wasn't immediately recognized in Notes, but after killing and restarting the Notes app, it worked.

**Update 2:** I've done a minimal test app with `myappname://` as a custom URL scheme. Again, like with the Twitter app, it worked after restarting the Notes app, so it doesn't seem related to the popularity of the app or whether it's been submitted or not.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've ever used textPlus, but it uses a URL scheme: tp:// and iOS recognizes it in Notes, Contacts, Messages, etc. Especially in Contacts, when you add a URL field to a contact, it somehow registers with the Contacts App as a URL type...

Comment: @RazorSharp It seems like tp:// is another scheme that iOS recognizes, then.  I know for a fact it can be finicky--I've tried opening links in UIWebViews like www.google.com--it doesn't work, I have to use http://www.google.com to get the page to load. So it sounds like you're going to need to use a scheme that iOS recognizes, whatever that may be.

Comment: You seem to be right, I just tested this with an Instacast `pcast://` URL and Instapaper's `ihttp://` (both are obviously not built-in) and they indeed seem to be recognized by Notes. New theory: Perhaps only URL schemes that are up to 5 letters long are recognized by the text system?

Comment: Okay, forget that, `tweetbot://` also works... No idea, maybe you need to restart the Notes app (or the device) for new URL schemes to be recognized...

Comment: Instapaper's ihttp:// is detected on my iPad even though it isn't installed. Most of these are very popular apps, is it possible that Apple just registers them b/c they're popular? Or maybe there is something in iTunes Connect?

Comment: That's another interesting theory, perhaps it only works for apps that have been submitted to the App Store.

Comment: Works like a charm! Just like what you said, I just restarted my device (which also closes and then reopens all apps) and it is recognized. So, as far as the cache theory, you're probably right! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't answer as to why it's not working (beyond guessing that the link interpreter is hard-coded to only recognize certain URL schemes), but I can say that the typical way around this is to link to a web page, and have the web page redirect to your custom scheme.

It's slightly less elegant, because the user will see Safari open up briefly before being forwarded to your app, but it's also more robust because the web page can provide a link to the app store to install the app if it is not installed on the user's phone.

Comment: I agree, I've had a horrible time trying to get links to work in messages. This open source stuff seems to be what you are describing: http://applinks.org/documentation/ (though in no way do I have anything to do with this project)