# iOS custom URL Scheme not recognized on incoming SMS

Tags: ios5

I created an iOS app that registers a new url scheme.
On my development phone, everything works fine. All urls of the new scheme appear underlined, as a link,  in the SMS app, notes, email and safari. I can click on the link and my app will be brought up.

However, when I distribute the app to other phones, using an Adhoc provisioning profile, the urls are not recognized *only* in incoming SMSs. If someone sends a message containing the url to me, it is not underlined as a link. If I send a message containing the url to myself, the link appears only in the sent message, not in the received message.

Has anyone been through this? Any ideas?
I ran out of options....

thanks!

Comment: this might be related to this question? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667030/app-url-is-not-being-detected-in-ios